# Homophone riddle 2

Tags: riddle, word

Just another homophone riddle

```
You can see me at a party or on the ground
Whichever one, it makes the same sound
If you find me on the ground you can pick me up
If you find me at a party, you probably can't
```

What are the homophones?

Hint:

> The one on the ground is very common

Comment: It is litter, though not balloons, rocks, or bases

Comment: I'm probably making homophone riddle 3 tomorrow, but I might do my own version of the name that name series.

Comment: Compliments to Xavier Stanton

Comment: You totally need to make that today!

Comment: Which one?  Name that name or homophone riddle 3

Comment: Homophone 3 of course; I love the homophone riddles. I think I'll make one too!

Comment: Ok, I will see which homophone hmmm...

Comment: I think I'm going to make a homonym riddle soon too! That'll make two riddles, and three homophones in this comment!

Comment: Ok, I think I've got em'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is it

> rapper and wrapper

Because

> Parties can have rappers while you can find wrappers on the ground. Also, you can pick up the wrapper from the ground but not the rapper from the party. Not sure exactly about the second clue though. Maybe because they can both make sounds?

Comment: I could see this being the answer.

Comment: And it is! Sorry I wasn't there 2 hours ago

Comment: Ohh, the second line was just restating that they were homophones, and it originally going to be a rhyming one, and it wouldn't say anywhere else that it was a homophone riddle but then I changed it

Comment: Oh so it just restates that they're homophones. Now the line makes sense to me.

Answer (score 3):

Probably wrong, but:

> BALLOON?

*You can see me at a party or on the ground*

> Balloons are often seen at birthday parties, but might also be lying around on the ground.

*Whichever one, it makes the same sound*

> BANG when you pop it.

*If you find me on the ground you can pick me up*

> Clearly.

*If you find me at a party, you probably can't*

> At a party they might be floating in the air, so you can't pick them up.

Comment: Sorry, good try though. The party is more of a public dancing sorta type party, not a birthday one

Comment: @Duck Another possibility would be to take the last three letters off this answer. A disco **** you can't lift, but a **** on the ground you can.

Comment: No, it is not that either, but you are closer than balloon

Comment: @Duck Closer in what way? :-P Similar word? Right kind of party?

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> Base and Bass

You can see me at a party or on the ground

> Music Base, and the base of somehing.

Whichever one, it makes the same sound

> Base and bass sound the same.

If you find me on the ground you can pick me up

> It is placed on the ground to hold stuff.

If you find me at a party, you probably can't

> You can't hold music like [1848 said](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/70882/homophone-riddle-2/70886#70886).

Comment: As I said earlier it's more of a person's job

Answer (score 2):

Could you be

> **FLOUR** and **FLOWER**?

`You can see me at a party or on the ground`

> At a **birthday party**, there is always cake, which has **flour**. 
>  On the ground, **flowers** can grow.

`Whichever one, it makes the same sound`

> That defines what a **homophone** is.

`If you find me on the ground you can pick me up` 
 `If you find me at a party, you probably can't`

> True for the first part. 
>  True for the second part, but not technically. Slices of cake containing flour can be picked up with a **utensil** (you yourself can't probably pick up the flour!), but obviously, the **purpose** of the action is to not actually pick it up; it is to **eat the cake**!

Also,

> Flour and flowers are not balloons, rocks or bases... but they are not really litter, either. I guess a flower could be litter, as the **archaic** definition of litter is the choice of bedding for a horse (that of which can include **plants**).

Comment: I like the answer ;) +1

Comment: @Duck thank you! I like the riddle ;) ... though unfortunately I have reached my daily voting limit, and I have to wait $9$ hours before I can vote again (DVL9).

Answer (score 1):

> Rock (stone) and rock (music)

because

> When you drop a rock, it makes a 'clank' sound. When you play rock music, it also makes 'harsh' sounds. They show up on the ground and at parties respectively.

Also,

> You can pick up stones, but I have yet to see a person pick up rock music sound waves.

Comment: So close!  It's more of a person though

Comment: Those are also homonyms, not homophones.

Comment: Yeah, you're right @PerpetualJ

Answer (score 1):

This could be;

> Chord and Cord

Found both at a party and on the ground:

> Chords are used in music to carry the tune. Cords have many uses but are often running along the ground in some manner.

Found on the ground you can pick it up;

> You can certainly pick cords up off the ground.

At a party you can’t;

> At a typical party you can’t raise the chords of a song (unless you’re a live band).

Comment: No, chords aren't a full time job, really

Comment: Think about it this way, who is the one making the chords or rock music or whatever

Answer (score 1):

New answer, will update;

> Band and Banned

Comment: I see you mean you can find like a rubber band on the ground or a hair band, but the line about parties isn't so clear so focus on the hint more

Comment: And the unclear line is more of a solo, kinda like a DJ at parties but a bit different